# jQuery UI Sortable items in one line should have the same height

Tags: css, jquery-ui, css-float, height, jquery-ui-sortable

I use jQuery UI Sortable to sort teasers. The problem ist, that sometimes the teasers include different amounts of text. (Red is text.) So if there is more than one line of teasers this happens:
[image]
But what I want is this:
[image]
The teasers should have the same height as the highest teaser in the line. It's no option to give them all the same height. The maximum count of teasers per line is always 3.

Is there an easier way than measuring the height of the highest teaser per line and adjust the height of the other teasers with jQuery after each sort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on DevIshOnes answer this is my solution:

```
var heights = [];
var tallest = [];
$('.teaser:not(.ui-sortable-placeholder)').each(function () {
  $(this).height('auto');
  heights.push($(this).height());
});
while (heights.length != 0) {
  var line = heights.splice(0,3);
  line.sort(function(a,b){return b-a});
  tallest.push(line[0]);
}
$('.teaser').each(function (i) {
  $(this).height(tallest[Math.floor(i/3)]);
});
```

To get the tallest teaser in each line I generate the `tallest` array and later I use `tallest[Math.floor(i/3)]` to get the correct height value for each teaser.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function () {
    $('li').addClass('teaser');
    $('.sortable').sortable();
    $('#fixHeights').click(function () {
        var heights = [];
        $('.teaser').each(function () {
            heights.push($(this).height());
        });
        heights.sort();
        var tallest = heights.pop();
        alert(tallest); // optional
        $('.teaser').each(function () {
            $(this).height(tallest);
        })
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle demo!](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/ZfHVw/1/)

> Is there an easier way than measuring the height of the highest teaser
>   per line and adjust the height of the other teasers with jQuery after
>   each sort?

Simply put, no.